# Make a whole div clickable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link inside a div and I need to make the whole div clickable... found several tutorials on the Internet but non of them worked for me...

Comment: Can you paste some code snippets here of what isn't working?

Comment: As I saw on the internet I should add the display:block attribute to the div but it doesn't work... besides I found one javascript solution but it didn't work as well: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/

Comment: Why is this tagged as css? Should be javascript.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're saying you want the entire div to be clickable for navigation, then you can either wrap it with an anchor () tag, which is not standards compliant, or add a css style to the contained anchor tag, making it the size of the containing div, which is standards compliant. I will use a div that is 250px by 250px in this example:

```
<div id="container"><a href="" style="display:block;width:250px;height:250px;">Link</a></div>
```

Comment: Why is it not standards compliant to have a `div` within an `a`? Is there a useful resource somewhere that dictates which elements can reside in which (I realize that block-level within inline is incorrect, but...)?

Comment: You cannot have a block display element contained in an inline element. That's right. It won't break your code in browsers, but it most likely will not validate correctly.

Glad I could help, Levani.

Comment: This is a really nice solution that avoids the classic javascript window.location='', thanks.

Answer (score 23):

**Raw JavaScript:**

```
<div onclick="alert('You clicked me !')">Click Me</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#div_id').click(function(){
  alert('Clicked !!');
});
```

**Update:** (With reference to your link)

```
<div class="myBox">
     blah blah blah.
    <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
     return false;
});
```

The above code cancels the default action of link (going to link) with `return false` and binds the `click` event to the div with class `myBox`, then it finds the link's `src` attribute inside the div and `window.location` is used to redirect the page to the `src` attribute of the link present inside the div. So this basically makes the div clickable.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem last year. I simply added an onclick to the div. Like so: `<div id="testimonial" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.location='http://www.mysite.com/testimonials.html'">`

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 it is now valid to have a **div** or whatever inside an **a**. That should do the trick. No scripts needed, unless that's what's in your link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JavaScript code at to achieve your goal,
please take a look at [this tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/).

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
     return false;
    });
```

and this is the HTML example :

```
<div class="myBox">
     blah blah blah.
    <a href="http://google.com">link</a></div>
```

but there is a tricky way to achieve this using a CSS code
you must nest an anchor tag inside your div tag and you must apply this property to it,

```
display:block;
```

when you've done that,it will make the whole width area clickable (but within the height of the anchor tag),if you want to cover the whole div area you must set the height of the anchor tag exactly to the height of the div tag,for example:

```
height:60px;
```

this is gonna make the whole area clickable,then you can apply `text-indent:-9999px` to anchor tag to achieve the goal.

this is really tricky and simple and it's just created using CSS code.

here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hbirjand/RG8wW/): http://jsfiddle.net/hbirjand/RG8wW/