# onclick in a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I want to run a JavaScript function by clicking a DIV.  This looks painfully simple from the examples you good folks have given, so I must be missing something very obvious.  My cursor behaves, but clicks do nothing.  I'd rather not get into jQuery.  Here's my entire file:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <META NAME="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <TITLE>BUG</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<div onclick="alert("Clicked");" style="cursor: pointer">
  <img src="test.jpg">
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292774/make-a-whole-div-clickable

Comment: Your code comprises issue on usage of double quote within double quote. Use either <div onclick="alert('Clicked');" style="cursor: pointer"> or
<div onclick='alert("Clicked");' style="cursor: pointer">

Comment: you should accept any of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div onclick="alert("Clicked");" style="cursor: pointer">
```

Misaligned quotes. You can use single quotes within the double quotes.

```
<div onclick="alert('Clicked');" style="cursor: pointer">
```

Comment: How very embarrassing.  Thank you all for not laughing hysterically. @ketan

Answer (score 2):

Double Quote is wrong. `onclick="alert("Clicked");"`

Use Single Quote in `onclick`:

```
<div onclick="alert('Clicked');" style="cursor: pointer">
  <img src="test.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onclick="alert("Clicked");" style="cursor: pointer">
```

you have used double quotes inside double quotes.

Use single quotes within double quote

```
<div onclick="alert('Clicked');" style="cursor: pointer">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
<p>Click the button to display an alert box:</p>

<div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</div>

 <script>
  function myFunction() {
   alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
```

Comment: How very embarrassing.  Thank you all for not laughing hysterically.   @Atul