# How to make a div clickable?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Make a whole div clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292774/make-a-whole-div-clickable)

I checked on couple of links. I understood it, yet it isn't working on mine.

Here is my code snippet:

```js
$('.Quiz').click(function(){
  window.location=$(this).find('a').attr('href');
  return false;
})
```

```css
.Portfolio {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 920px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;

    margin-top: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;

    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #dddddd;

    border-width: 2px;

    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;

    overflow: auto;
}

.port {
    color: #4aaaa5;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #cccccc;

    border-width: 2px;
    border-left-style: hidden;
    border-right-style: hidden;
    border-top-style: hidden;
}

.container_img  img{
    float:left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px; 
    position: relative;

}

.container h1 {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding: 20px;
}

.Books{
    clear:left;
}

.Books h1{
    clear:left;
}

.Kernel{
    clear: left;
}

.Kernel h1{
    clear: left;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.text_m h1{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;

    background: #4aaaa5;
    opacity: 0.7;
    width:210px;

    margin-top: 200px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.text_e h1{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

    text-align: center;
    color: white;

    background: #4aaaa5;
    opacity: 0.7;
    width:230px;

    margin-top: 200px;
    right: 250px;

}

.text_b h1{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Portfolio">

<div class="port"> 
    <h1> Portfolio </h1>
</div>  

<div class="container_img"> 
    <div class="Quiz"> 
        <a href="https://madhumitha.github.io/Quiz/"></a>
        <img  src="assets/images/quiz.jpg" alt="Quiz">
            <div class='text_m'> 
                <h1> Quiz Time </h1>
            </div>
    </div>


    <div class="Weather"> 
        <img src="assets/images/Weather.jpg" alt="Weather">
            <div class='text_e'>
                <h1 id='weather'> Weather </h1>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Books">
        <img src="assets/images/space.jpg" alt="Space"> 
            <div class='text_b'>
                <h1> ISS-Tracker </h1>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Photography">
        <img src="assets/images/Photography.jpg" alt="Photography">
            <div class='text_p'>
                <h1> Photography </h1>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Kernel">
        <img src="assets/images/Kernel.jpg" alt="Kernel">
            <div class='text_k'>
                <h1> Kernel </h1>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>           
</div>
```

I'm trying to make the div clickable for first image. I can't figure out what's going wrong? Whether click event doesn't work with float and clear in css or not?

Comment: What do you get in the browser console if you add `console.log($('.Quiz').length)` directly before your `$('.Quiz').click` code?

Comment: Are there any browser errors (eg is jquery not loading correctly)?  Have you wrapped your `.click` event in doc ready? `$(function() { $(".Quiz").click...`

Comment: Clearly, there's nothing wrong with your code as-is so there must be some other issue - eg running the code before the div exists (hence add to doc ready) or the div is loaded later.   The conversion to a snippet shows that it works fine because snippets handle this thing for you - that may not be how you have it in your code.

Comment: On adding ```console.log($('.Quiz').length```, it returns 0

Comment: No. But it worked once I included it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [HTML5](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/a.html#a-changes) it's perfectly valid to put a `div` inside of an `a` tag.

```
<a href="https://madhumitha.github.io/Quiz/">
  <div class="Quiz"> 
    <img  src="assets/images/quiz.jpg" alt="Quiz">
    <div class='text_m'> 
      <h1> Quiz Time </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing `$(document).ready()` this fixed the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($('.Quiz').length);

    $('.Quiz').click(function(){
        window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Any reason you're using jQuery for this instead of just a basic html link?

Answer (score 0):

You need to push child elements of Quiz div into anchor and then set width and height of anchor according to your need and also set style display block into anchor tag.

```
<div class="Quiz"> 
     <a href="https://madhumitha.github.io/Quiz/" style="display:block">
        <img  src="assets/images/quiz.jpg" alt="Quiz">
            <div class='text_m'> 
                <h1> Quiz Time </h1>
            </div>
     </a>
</div>
```